# Changing function's parameter value inside its body

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Why I still allowed to do this?

```
  @spec url_hash(String.t) :: String.t
  def url_hash(url) do
    url = String.replace(url, ~r/\s/, "")
    Base.encode16(:crypto.hash(:md5, url), case: :lower)
  end
```

Instead of, **what I think** a proper functional programming paradigm?

```
  @spec url_hash2(String.t) :: String.t
  def url_hash2(url) do
    url_copy = String.replace(url, ~r/\s/, "")
    Base.encode16(:crypto.hash(:md5, url_copy), case: :lower)
  end
```

As you can see, I'm modifying parameter value inside the function body.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff so dangling pointer is pretty much a norm?

Comment: Did you bother to check URL after you return from the function?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I got it after read the linked answer, scope things

Answer (score -1):

Pure functional languages wouldn't let you do this, and even some impure functional languages like Erlang. The convention in Erlang is to have code equivalent to this:

```
def url_hash(url) do
  url1 = some_func(url)
  url2 = some_other_func(url1)
  url3 = yet_another_func(url2)
  url3
end
```

The problem is that it gets pretty painful to reorder or add new lines of code when you do that. For this reason, Jose made the decision to allow variable reassignment. However, the original `url` string is unmodified - you've simply changed which String `url` points to.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: @RamonSnir Relevance? Both example functions are in isolated scopes, not nested scopes.